# Cant get results out database oophp, mysqli

Tags: php, oop, pdo

im trying to understand oophp a litle bit but now im stuck in getting information out of my database. What am i doing wrong? After the tip off PDO I tried the following but also no results...

index.php

```
<?php
include('classes/database.class.php');

$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$res = $db->select();  
print_r($res); 
?>
```

database.class.php

```
<?php
    class Database  {

        private $db_host = 'localhost';     // Database Host
        private $db_user = 'root';          // Gebruikersnaam
        private $db_pass = 'root';          // Passwoord
        private $db_name = 'quickscans';    // Database naam

        public function connect()
        {
            try
            {
                $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_name,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


        public function disconnect()    
        {
            $db = null;
        }  


        public function select()    
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT id FROM bedrijf';
            $results = $db->query($sql);

            foreach($results as $row)
            {
                echo $row['id'].'<br>';
            }
        }
    }  
?>
```

Maybe this code is a bit cleaner.. but still no results :(.

Comment: `getResult()` returns `$this->result` which is virtually `private $result = array();` Think so. Learning OO myself.

Comment: Whats the reason you write your own class instead of using (for example) `PDO`?

Comment: Yea its the same, but with the function select i change the result... (although thats the idea)...

Comment: @KingCrunch He said he's learning oo.

Comment: Can you post the output you do get, if any?  Just trying to make sure the connection is going through.

Comment: Also, and just an initial observation, your select method isn't returning anything for print_r to output, but rather echoing directly.  You should return the whole results array in this method and do the output in the calling context.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning any instance variables in this class.

The query method has no access to the connection you create because the object has no state.

Your constructor for the class should create the connection, and then queries can be called on this property.

```
class Database  {

private $db_host = 'localhost';     // Database Host
private $db_user = 'root';          // Gebruikersnaam
private $db_pass = 'root';          // Passwoord
private $db_name = 'quickscans';    // Database naam

public function __construct(){
  $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    try
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_name,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}


public function disconnect()    
{
    $this->connection = null;
}  


public function select()    
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM bedrijf';
    $results = $this->connection->query($sql);

    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        echo $row['id'].'<br>';
    }
}
}
```

The $this keyword sets instance variables for the class, so the `connection` property becomes a PDO instance that other methods can act upon.  Without this, the varibles created in the methods, in this case `$db` are just orphaned in the local function scope and not accessible in the greater class.

Utilizing this approach elminates the need to run `connect()` in the calling context.  You don't need to use the constructor to do this if you don't want to, you'll just always need to connect first in order to create the connection property and have it available to the rest of the class.  Also note you can name the property whatever you like, I just used `connection` because it made the most sense in the API.

Also, as commented, to make this a bit more usable you should have the select method return the query results array rather than having it output directly.

```
public function select()    
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id FROM bedrijf';
        $results = $this->connection->query($sql);
        if(!empty($results)){
          return $results
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be an part of the solluction, the only thing i get now is: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id FROM bedrijf ), so how can i echo/print the results?

Comment: @Augus - The PDOStatement object is an iterable just like an array.  You can print it out with a foreach loop just like you did in your original calling context.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php